# Difference between JDBC Sink Connector vs Redshift Sink Connector

Tags: apache-kafka, amazon-redshift, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I'm new to Kafka and I would like to know why there are specific Database connectors like Redshift Sink Connector and why we should not go for generic JDBC sink connectors. What are the advantages or differences between both.

Also, the Redshift Sink connector is giving me poor performance. Is there anyway to improve the same?

Answer (score 0):

> why there are specific Database connectors like Redshift Sink Connector

Because there is a [Java AWS SDK written for Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/using-aws-sdk-for-java.html), and this is what that connector uses.

The JDBC Sink connector has no hard-dependency on the AWS SDK

> why we should not go for generic JDBC sink connectors

Ideally, you don't want to expose your AWS credentials in the Connect API configurations, I assume.

Also, the Redshift JDBC "dialect" might not be supported by the Confluent Connector